# Partial Differentiation - Widder's Advanced Calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation

I am struggling with this problem from Widder's "Advanced Calculus" (Chapter 1 section 1 problem 2 of the first edition).

> If $f(x,y,z) = x\log(y^2) +ye^z$, find $f_2(x,xy,y-z)$.

Specifically, I don't understand what the notation $f_2(x,xy,y+z)$ means. Am I supposed to differentiate with respect to $y$ and then substitute $y=xy$ and $z=y+z$?

Note: it seems that Widder uses "log" meaning "ln". Does anyone know why?

Comment: Ok, sorry. Wrote the problem instead.

Comment: With regard to $\log$, some texts use that for the natural logarithm because usually it's the only one we care about. Everything else follows from change-of-base.

Comment: Mathematicians (not writing elementary calculus books) tend to use log for ln. Your interpretation is correct. If the author intended you to define $g(x,y,z)=f(x,xy,y-z)$ and then calculate $g_2(x,y,z)$, he should have written that. The whole point is to distinguish between the derivative of $f(x^2)$ and the derivative of $f$ at $x^2$.

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation  would be ; $$f(r,s,t)=2r\ln s+se^t,$$$$ g(x,y,z)=f(x,xy,y-z)$$$$\text{ Find }\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}.$$